# Can i sell ticket in an iphone app without IAP

Tags: iphone, ios4, in-app-purchase

I'm building a app for an online service that sell tickets on their website.
We want to allow people to buy ticket from the iphone but we can't use in app purchase as it cost too much.

So my question is, can we have a button on the Event detail view "View Tickets", then when clicked do on of the follow preferably the 1:

1. Open a webview from the app that display the mobile optimized website.
2. Open safari on the event detail screen.

Thanks.

Comment: since the offtopic voters are coming your way you (and everybody else who likes to ask questions about app stores) should commit to the [app stores stackexchange site proposal on area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores?referrer=jcBbxTFsYbhSPTdluUKgFA2). That site would be the perfect place for such questions.

Comment: Thanks for the tips... didn't know.

Comment: @clide313 have you been successfull? how did you manage to implement the payments? did you app get approved?

Comment: Good questions... I'm curious to know too??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do that. In fact that is the only way to do it, IAP does not allow you to make such purchases.

See the [App Store Review Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html):

> 11.3 Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the application will be rejected

Comment: Thank you very much. So both ways will do the trick... don't need to open safari?