# iPhone App - using inApp purchasers in Shopping cart

Tags: in-app-purchase, shopping-cart

I want to integrate payment gate way in my iPhone Shopping cart App. Since Apple doesn't allow to use third party payment gateway and Paypal doesn't support in my country only option is inApp purchase. I wondering what is the percentage Apple charge. I know they charge 30% for digital products like Apps, musics is same percentage applys for all?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the below question

[Can i sell ticket in an iphone app without IAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864048/can-i-sell-ticket-in-an-iphone-app-without-iap/8864081#8864081)

You cannot use inApp purchases for all kinds of products. You can use your own payment gateway to get things done.